# How to filter bad and good json events and then increment metrics count for bad json record and store those record in apache beam using java

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have PubSub topic having json raw message events, I want to filter good json record/events and bad json records/ events and store in different PCollections. For each bad record counter metrics should be increase and store logs in another PCollections so that later I can check the logs for bad json records. Which Apache beam transform i need to use and how to use those transform using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the [beam programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/). You will find great solution and pattern for your use case. For example, to filter the good and the bad JSON, you need to create a transform with a standard output (let's say the correct JSON) and [an addition output](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs) for the bad JSON.

So, from there, you have 2 PCollections. Then process them idependently. You can sink the bad JSON in a file, in BigQuery, or simply create a transform that write a special log trace in Cloud Logging to get and process this log trace later in another process if you want.